# Why does my list not align horizontally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite new to CSS and bootstrap here.

I am trying to align a list on the navbar horizontally but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Instead of aligning them side by side, it seems to align one below the other, which is not what I'm looking for.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contents="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/terms.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>
<title>Terms of Service</title>

</head>
<body>
    <!--Header-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Bet Coins">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#"><b>Terms of Service<b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>Legal Guidelines</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.navbar{height:95px;}

.body{background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;}

.navbar-nav li a{line-height: 64px;}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: put  display: inline; in your li element. Like this `.navbar-nav li{ display: inline;}`

Comment: That didn't work. It just made the list shift a bit more up.

Comment: Try `display:inline-block`, it would have been great if you provided with the jsfiddle

Comment: That didn't work either :(
Unfortunately, the code doesn't show up properly in JSFiddle, that's why I avoided providing the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really small thing, but you need to be careful to close all your tags properly; if you close the `<b>` tags in your `<li>` then it works. Apart from that your markup is correct. It should look like this:

```
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><b>Terms of Service</b></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><b>Legal Guidelines</b></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </li>
```

I also added a closing slash to the `<img>` tag here:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Bet Coins" />
```

but I think that's less crucial than closing the `<b>` tags properly.

Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6804py5w/1/